# Exibir e ocultar campos conforme o checkbox for selecionado

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Preciso que para cada uma dessas opções do checkbox (se ela for selecionada) mostre o campo input relacionado a cada um deles. Mas quando seleciono o checkbox não mostra o campo texto relacionado a ele que deveria ser exibido.

Aqui o script que estou utilizando

$('#quais_redes input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    let name = this.value;
    $('[data-label=' + name + ']').css('display', this.checked ? '' : 'none');
    });

```
                                              <div class="form-group">
                        <label for ="quais_redes" id="quais_redes">Possui redes sociais?</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-check-input" id="rede_facebook" type="checkbox" name="redes[]" value="1">
                                    Facebook
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-check-input" id="rede_instagram" type="checkbox" name="redes[]" value="2">
                                    Instagram
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-check-input" id="rede_twitter" type="checkbox" name="redes[]" value="3">
                                    Twitter
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-check-input" id="rede_telegram" type="checkbox" name="redes[]" value="4">
                                    Telegram
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-check-input" id="rede_whatsapp" type="checkbox" name="redes[]" value="5">
                                    Whatsapp
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 auto; display: none;">
                            <label for="instagram">Qual o seu Facebook?</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="facebook" id="facebook" data-label="rede_facebook">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 auto; display: none;">
                            <label for="instagram">Qual o seu Instagram?</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="instagram" id="instagram" data-label="rede_instagram">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 auto; display: none;">
                            <label for="twitter">Qual o seu Twitter?</label>
                            <input type="text" name="twitter" class="form-control" id="twitter" data-label="rede_twitter">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 auto; display: none;">
                            <label for="twitter">Qual o seu Telegram?</label>
                            <input type="text" name="telegram" class="form-control" id="telegram" data-label="rede_telegram">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 auto; display: none;">
                            <label for="twitter">Qual o seu Whatsapp?</label>
                            <input type="text" name="whatsapp" class="form-control" id="whatsapp" data-label="rede_whatsapp">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: E como tentou fazer com JS? Poderia postar o código e descrever o resultado obtido?

Comment: Sim, claro! Então, eu acabei usando esse script, tentei fazer um teste só com um campo mesmo pra ver se funcionava mas não rolou. 

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#rede_facebook').on('input', function(){
    $('#facebook').prop('disabled', false);
  });
});

E coloquei o disable no campo do facebook. 
Só que o campo só fica desabilitado e não habilita. Mas na realidade não era pra aparecer o campo antes deu selecionar o checkbox, e ele aparece mesmo sem clicar no checkbox e fica sempre desabilitado.

Comment: Seria importante vc tb incluir na sua pergunta o CSS e o JS que vc tentou, assim da para ver ando vc está errando

Comment: Sim, Hugo. Mas parando pra analisar, o código do Javascript que eu tinha colocado ele não estava servindo para ocultar e sim somente para desabilitar, sabe? Eu preciso que ele fique oculto, não desabilitado. Então de qualquer forma tava errada a forma que eu estava fazendo mas vou colocar aqui.

Comment: Galera, tentei resolver usando Ajax mas não funcionou também, vou editar a postagem colocando essa forma que eu fiz q ta mais completa que a anterior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, existem algumas incoerências no seu código, e coisas que não estão batendo. Arrumei aqui está funcionando perfeitamente, as etapas:

A tag `label for="quais_redes"` logo no começo, está sendo um `label` para a própria `label`, só está servindo como um texto apenas, e no caso do jQuery na `$('#quais_redes input')` não existe input no `quais_redes` como dito antes é um `label` que não está fazendo nada alí. E em vez de `quais_redes` pode-se notar que a `div` que engloba esses `checkbox`, é a `div` com a `class="col-sm-10"`, e os inputs estão dentro dela, assim você poderia detectar mudanças dos `checkbox` com o `change()` através dela.

No próximo, `let name = this.value` ao qual ele irá trazer esse value para pegar outro elemento com o `data-label` `=` `name`, porém você pode observar que os `values` dos `inputs` `checkbox` são numeros 1,2,3,4 e 5 e o `data-label` dos elementos que contém o atributo `data-label` são **rede_*nomeDaRedeSocial*** e não números, logo o que realmente você está querendo pegar para pegar os inputs com o atributo `data-label` são os `id` dos `input[type="checkbox"]`, observe o **`id`** dos `checkbox` são **rede_*nomeDaRedeSocial***, ou seja em vez de `let name = this.value` seria `let name = this.id`

E por último no `css()` do jQuery, cada elemento com o `[data-label="name"]` está dentro do de uma `div` com a `class="form-group"` e pode notar que é essa `div` que tem o `display='none'` do css, ao qual vc quer alterar, e não o `[data-label="name"]` em si, até então é essa `div` pai que tem o atributo `style`. Assim você pode usar o `parent()` do jQuery que pega o elemento pai. Ou seja com o `parent()` ele vai pegar o elemento Pai do elemento com o data-label ao qual você está procurando, e em vai mudar o `css` dele, no caso o `display`.

#### Assim o jQuery ficaria:

```js
$('.col-sm-10 input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
        let name = this.id
        $('[data-label="' + name + '"]').parent().css('display', this.checked ? '' : 'none' )
    })
```

### Código Inteiro:

```js
    $('.col-sm-10 input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
        let name = this.id
        $('[data-label="' + name + '"]').parent().css('display', this.checked ? '' : 'none' )
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
        <label for ="quais_redes" id="quais_redes">Possui redes sociais?</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" id="rede_facebook" type="checkbox" name="redes[]" value="1">
                    Facebook
            </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" id="rede_instagram" type="checkbox" name="redes[]" value="2">
                    Instagram
            </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" id="rede_twitter" type="checkbox" name="redes[]" value="3">
                    Twitter
            </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" id="rede_telegram" type="checkbox" name="redes[]" value="4">
                    Telegram
            </div>

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" id="rede_whatsapp" type="checkbox" name="redes[]" value="5">
                    Whatsapp
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 auto; display: none;">
            <label for="instagram">Qual o seu Facebook?</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="facebook" id="facebook" data-label="rede_facebook">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 auto; display: none;">
            <label for="instagram">Qual o seu Instagram?</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="instagram" id="instagram" data-label="rede_instagram">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 auto; display: none;">
            <label for="twitter">Qual o seu Twitter?</label>
            <input type="text" name="twitter" class="form-control" id="twitter" data-label="rede_twitter">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 auto; display: none;">
            <label for="twitter">Qual o seu Telegram?</label>
            <input type="text" name="telegram" class="form-control" id="telegram" data-label="rede_telegram">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 auto; display: none;">
            <label for="twitter">Qual o seu Whatsapp?</label>
            <input type="text" name="whatsapp" class="form-control" id="whatsapp" data-label="rede_whatsapp">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: muito obrigada, NoFace! :)